# Is there a command line interface to Keychain's / the system Password Assistant utility?

Tags: macos, password, keychain

[image: random passwords as provided by the Password Assistant utility]

When creating keychain records, changing your user password, and various other security-minded aspects of the system, there is a little key icon you can click on that opens the above Password Assistant utility. It is a very simple utility that has a small handful of Password types;

- "Memorable" (pictured)
- Letters & Numbers
- Numbers Only
- Random
- FIPS-181 compliant

Then you choose a password length, and it gives you a random password, whose dropdown can be expanded for other suggestions matching your requirements.

This utility is straight-forward, and incredibly helpful, ESPECIALLY the 'Memorable' generator type. Is there a means of directly invoking the Password Assistant alone, either via the command line alone, or a command line command that launches the assistant, then returns the selected password on the command line?

The "cleanest" way I've found so far is to open Keychain Access.app, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>, then click the Key icon to open the Assistant dialog. However, the mouse-centric nature of this is a nuisance to me when I just want to generate a password.

This does not appear to exist under the `security` Keychain command line utility as far as I can discern from its man page, any place where you would create an entry using `security` it prompts you for a password.

I've never seen any other generator that creates a pleasant 'Memorable' mix as this utility does, and I'd like to delegate to it's capabilities directly from any integrable aspect of MacOS systems.

Comment: A really nice idea for a CLI tool project!

Comment: Great to meet you here again Jason. Is your requirement to have a keychain entry left behind or simply to get out a string and not leave any remnants of the generated result?

Comment: I’d like a password, no Keychain artifacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Memorable" password generation option appears to be gone in MacOS Catalina, there is now only;

- Manual
- Letters & Numbers
- Numbers Only
- Random
- FIPS-181 compliant

The `security` command line tool doesn't seem to generate passwords, it will only accept one you define. If there's another command line tool for password generation built into the OS that re-uses the above options, I don't know about it.

Given the combination of both of those factors, I'm documenting and accepting this answer as closure.

Comment: I wonder if "Memorable" had too little entropy or something of the sort. ISTR something similar with Airport device passwords, or Safari password suggestions, or something else in that realm.

Comment: This would have been a great question to self answer in winter bash!

Comment: I remembered what I was thinking of; Personal Hotspot automatically generated Wi-Fi passwords prior to iOS 6 or so had too little entropy. They were something like 8 or 10 alphanumerics, it was increased and last I knew, at least the Wi-Fi password I have on my Personal Hotspot still to this day, is now 13 alphanumerics.